# Ayuda con expression Lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, lambda

estoy trabajando con asp mvc y en mi controlador tengo un ActionResult que contiene lambda pero me muestra el siguiente error en la variable local 'union' despues del request

> A local or parameter named 'union' cannot be dfeclared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Codigo:

```
 public ActionResult Union_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        IQueryable<Union> union = db.Union;
        DataSourceResult result = union.ToDataSourceResult(request, union => new {
            ID = union.ID,
            FECHA = union.FECHA,
            NO_DOCUMENTO = union.NO_DOCUMENTO,
            ID_CLIENTE = union.ID_CLIENTE,
            NOMBRE_CLIENTE = union.NOMBRE_CLIENTE,
            ID_ARTICULO = union.ID_ARTICULO,
            DESCRIPCION = union.DESCRIPCION,
            CANT = union.CANT,
            UND = union.UND,
            PRECIO_VENTA = union.PRECIO_VENTA,
            DESCUENTO = union.DESCUENTO,
            IMPUESTO = union.IMPUESTO,
            Nombre = union.Nombre,
            PROVINCIA = union.PROVINCIA,
            Expr1 = union.Expr1,
            VENTA = union.VENTA,
            Region = union.Region
        });

        return Json(result);
    }
```

Comment: Te lo está diciendo: no puedes usar `union` para las 2 cosas. Cambia el nombre de tu variable `IQueryable< Union > uni = db.Union;`.

Comment: Voto por cerrarla por *error tipográfico*.